# Apache + mod_wsgi + django: send a default response for a backlogged request

Tags: django, timeout, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I am running a web server using Apache 2.4, mod_wsgi, and Django. The server overloads occasionally due to high traffic. I want to setup the server such that it responds with a pre-determined default response to backlogged requests (i.e., requests that have been waiting in the queue over a certain timeout). What is the best way to do this? Additionally, I want to the keep the connection alive after sending the default response.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure `mod_wsgi` with a short timeout, then customize the timeout error in Apache. For example, if you want it to happen after ten seconds, you could set `request-timeout=10` as an option of `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive.

Then, you could configure Apache to display a custom error message for timeouts:
`ErrorDocument 504 "We're too busy right now, the hamsters are exhausted!"` You can also configure a custom HTML page, or URL: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Do this all within a `VirtualHost` and it will be locally scoped. Good luck!